# Access File Uploaded Attributes in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, file-upload

I upload a file

In my **controller**, I did this

```
$file = Input::file('file');
dd($file);
```

I see this

```
Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#1388 ▼
  -test: false
  -originalName: "config-nsd-got.yaml"
  -mimeType: "application/x-yaml"
  -error: 0
  #hashName: null
  path: "/private/var/tmp"
  filename: "phpb73hcy"
  basename: "phpb73hcy"
  pathname: "/private/var/tmp/phpb73hcy" <<<<<<---------- I WANT TO ACCESS THIS
  extension: ""
  realPath: false
  writable: false
  readable: false
  executable: false
  file: false
  dir: false
  link: false
}
```

I want to `pathname: "/private/var/tmp/phpb73hcy"`,

I've tried

```
dd($file->pathname());
dd($file["pathname"]);
```

I just want this `/private/var/tmp/phpb73hcy`

## Any hints for me ?

Comment: `->getRealPath()` perhaps?

Comment: Try `$file->getPathname()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$this->getPathname()`.

The Laravel `UploadedFile` class extends the Symfony [`UploadedFile`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.php) class, which extends the Symfony [`File`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/File.php) class, which extends the PHP [`SplFileInfo`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php) class. The latter has the `getPathname()` method.

Comment: i seek for size and getSize worked for me

Answer (score 1):

From Matt Stauffer's book **Laravel Up and Running**:

> Every uploaded file is a descendant of the [`SplFileInfo`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php) class, which provides a `getRealPath()` method that returns the path to the file's location.

```
$path = $file->getRealPath();
dd($path);
```